# Can I bind (in a more low level way than AutoHotKey) Ctrl+Tab to Alt+Tab in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My mind is irrevocably programmed to switch applications by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> while depressing the key immediately to the left of the spacebar. I think it's got something to do with the way the hand is positioned on the keyboard naturally and hitting any modifier key other than <kbd>Alt</kbd> with the thumb is quite awkward.

This has made my transition to Macs quite a bit easier than it could have been.

I now dual boot Windows 8 Release Preview and OS X Lion on my Macbook Air and it simply takes too much mental processing to have to consider the OS I am running in order to perform the correct task.

So what I intend to do is to bind the <kbd>Command</kbd> key (which functions as the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key now) to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key so that I can comfortably save my files and close windows and whatnot, because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> being usable by the thumb is fantastic, but this leaves the problem with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I will surely resort to the dead simple AutoHotKey solution but I was wondering if there is some way I can hack the registry (I have used a program called KeyTweak to set these registry settings to achieve the aforementioned <kbd>Windows</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> mapping) so that **only** <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will fire <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>? (To get an actual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> I could use <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>.)

Comment: So, the reason you don't want to use AutoHotkey is you don't want to have to run AHK in the background?

Comment: Basically. I don't want to run a program in the background if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easily (maybe not at all) possible without AutoHotKey.